# C - Sending Modified String Over Sockets

Tags: c, string, sockets

I'm trying to send a modified string over sockets. The goal is to take a string from the client, add something to it, then send it back. The strings are passed in command line arguments. Right now, I can receive the message from the client, but for some reason my `recvfrom` function is returning `-1` which causes the client to get hung up and not receive the `sendto` from the server. It seems like the server is modifying the string fine, but I can't get it to receive correctly on the other side. I have print statements in my code for testing purposes. The command line arguments for the client are server name, port number, string. The command line arguments for the server are port number, string to concatenate. Below is my code:

headerFiles.h:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

server.c:

```
#include "headerFiles.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int s;
    int len;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
    int clntAddrLen;
    int serverPort;
    char catStringMeow[256];

    serverPort = atoi(argv[1]);
    strcpy(catStringMeow, argv[2]);

    // Build local (server) socket address
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    // Create socket
    if((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: socket failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Bind socket to local address and port
    if((bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0))
    {
        perror("Error: bind failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;) // Runs forever
    {
        printf("buffer = %s\n", buffer);
        printf("In for\n");
        // Receive String
        len = recvfrom(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
        printf("Received %d bytes\n", len);

        printf("buffer = %s\n", buffer);
        strcat(buffer, " ");
        strcat(buffer, catStringMeow);
        printf("New string = %s\n",buffer);
        printf("buffer size = %d\n", (int)strlen(buffer));
        len = (int)strlen(buffer);

        // Send String
        sendto(s, buffer, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, sizeof(clntAddr));
        printf("Sent %d bytes\n", len);
    }
}
```

client.c:

```
#include "headerFiles.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) // Three arguments to be checked later
{
    int s; // Socket descriptor
    int len; // Length of string to be echoed
    char* servName; // Server name
    int servPort; // Server port
    char* string; // String to be echoed
    char buffer[256+1]; // Data buffer
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr; // Server socket address

    // Check and set program arguments
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Error: three arguments are needed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    servName = argv[1];
    servPort = atoi(argv[2]);
    string = argv[3];

    // Build server socket address
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, servName, &servAddr.sin_addr);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);

    // Create socket
    if((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: Socket failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Send echo string
    len = sendto(s, string, strlen(string), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    printf("Sent %d bytes\n", len);

    // Receive echo string
    len = recvfrom(s, buffer, len, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("Received\n");

    //Print and verify echoed string
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    printf("Echo string received: ");
    fputs(buffer, stdout);
    printf("\n");

    // Close the socket
    close(s);

    // Stop the program
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `strcat(buffer, " ");` buffer is **not** nul-terminated. you have `len = recvfrom(...)` :: use it.

Comment: `len` evaluates to -1 because that is what `recvfrom` is returning. I can't use it. There is something wrong with the `recvfrom` function.

Comment: When a system call returns `-1`, it means it got an error, and `errno` contains the error code. Call `perror()` to print the reason.

Comment: note that you send a message that is len long, add something to it and then try to receive into a len long buffer. Thats not going to work

Comment: Barmar, it says `invalid argument`

Comment: pm100, how do I get the client to receive it with the modified length?

Comment: ' len long, add something to it and then try to receive into a len long buffer' - so len is an invalid argument, as posted by @Barmar.  Job done:)

Comment: Use a bigger buffer.  A huge buffer.  64k would be fine for all datagrams, so use 64k.

Comment: Martin, I'm sorry, but I'm not following...

Comment: Find where you typed '256+1'.  delete those characters and, in their place, put '65536'.

Comment: Martin, this doesn't seem to fix anything and -1 is still returned from the `recvfrom` on the server side

Comment: You are getting `errno` 1 which means `invalid argument` because `recvfrom()` is expecting the size of the client address but you sent it unknown value. Try initializing `int clntAddrLen` with `int clntAddrLen=sizeof(clntAddr)`.

Comment: alvits, That fixed my send problem, thank you! I increased the buffer size on the receive size to a hard coded value, but is there anyway to make it a value that is just right? With a large number it sends and receives just fine, but that seems rather inefficient.

Comment: Maybe it's best to post that as another question instead of changing the course of this post.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
   // Receive echo string
    len = recvfrom(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("Received\n");
```

and make buffer bigger.

Comment: and did it fail for the same reason?

Comment: Right now I am reverting back to my original code where I have just the string echo. It works fine. When I add:

`char catThisString[256];`
`strcpy(cat, argv[2]);`

It messes up. Nothing gets sent back and forth anymore.

Comment: thats becasue you are adding a lot of garbage - see wildplasser comment

Comment: Sorry this isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an uninitizlied `clntAddrLen` value to `recvfrom`, which is resulting in the `Invalid argument` error code. According to the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom):

> The argument `addrlen` is a value-result argument, which the caller should initialize before the call to the size of the buffer associated with `src_addr`, and modified on return to indicate the actual size of the source address.

So you need to initialize it with:

```
clntAddrLen = sizeof(clntAddr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize the client address length variable before using it in sendto or recvfrom.

The problem is that on the first calling to sendto from client.c, the servers sees the client's ip as 0.0.0.0, after that on the second, third,... calls the client.c get an ip and have a legal ip such as 127.0.0.3:3212.

You can see that second, third, ... clients work.

Initialize length variable to sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)